# Как перевести определенные ячейки таблицы с помощью стилей?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть интересная задачка с соседними селекторами и псевдоэлементами.

Табличка для брони отелей.

Хочу в ней заменить слова в табличке "Adults" на "Взрослые", "Children" на "Дети" "Discount" на "Скидка" используя только стили и не меняя `html` структуры при этом (не дописывая классов, ид, тегов), без скриптов.

Как этого можно добиться?

Проблема в том, что выбирая соседние элементы после селектора с классом `separator` накладываются стили и на последующие строки таблицы.

```css
.dopbsp-line {
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.dopbsp-cart tr.dopbsp-separator + tr td.dopbsp-label {
  font-size: 0;
}
.dopbsp-cart tr.dopbsp-separator + tr td.dopbsp-label:before {
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "Взрослые";
}
```

```html
<table class="dopbsp-cart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Check in</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value">14 06 2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Check out</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value">24 06 2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Price</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-price">110$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
      <td class="dopbsp-label">
        <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value">
        <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Adults</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Children</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
      <td class="dopbsp-label">
        <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value">
        <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dopbsp-label">Discount</td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">-20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
      <td class="dopbsp-label"></td>
      <td class="dopbsp-value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения используем псевдокласс `:nth-child`.

> Пример использования `tr:nth-child(3)`

`tr` - это тег, `nth-child(3)` - означает что нужно обратиться к тегу `tr` который по счёту третий!

`.dopbsp-cart` - можно сказать что это родительский класс в котором нужно считать.

`.dopbsp-cart > tr:nth-child(3)` - это говорит нам что нужно обратиться к классу `dopbsp-cart` в котором есть `tr` по счёту 3.

> Считать нужно теги от 1 до n(-го) числа.

```css
    .dopbsp-line {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }       
    
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(3)> .dopbsp-label{
        font-size:0;
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(5)> .dopbsp-label{
        font-size:0;
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(6)> .dopbsp-label{
        font-size:0;
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(8)> .dopbsp-label{
        font-size:0;
    }
    
    
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(3) > .dopbsp-label:before {
      font-size: 14px;
      content: "Цена";
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(5) > .dopbsp-label:before {
      font-size: 14px;
      content: "Взрослые";
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(6) > .dopbsp-label:before {
      font-size: 14px;
      content: "Дети";
    }
    .dopbsp-cart tr:nth-child(8) > .dopbsp-label:before {
      font-size: 14px;
      content: "Скидка";
    }
```

```html
    <table class="dopbsp-cart">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Check in</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value">14 06 2019</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Check out</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value">24 06 2019</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Price</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-price">110$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
          <td class="dopbsp-label">
            <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value">
            <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Adults</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Children</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
          <td class="dopbsp-label">
            <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value">
            <div class="dopbsp-line"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dopbsp-label">Discount</td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value dopbsp-info">-20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dopbsp-separator">
          <td class="dopbsp-label"></td>
          <td class="dopbsp-value"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```